# Mysql select not duplicated values with condition

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I'm looking for faster way to run this kind of statment:

```
SELECT *
FROM `aukcje_przedmioty`
WHERE (
(
    opis NOT
    IN (
        SELECT opis
        FROM aukcje_przedmioty
        WHERE ( aktywne =1 AND user_id =6 )
    )
)
AND aktywne =0
AND user_id =6
)
```

table aukcje_przedmioty

Comment: post the structure for table aukcje_przedmioty please

Comment: structure: |id|user_id|title|opis|aktywne|

Comment: opis is a text, aktywne is int with only two values 1 or 0, id and user id is int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `aukcje_przedmioty` a 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT opis,user_id
  FROM aukcje_przedmioty
  GROUP BY opis,user_id
  HAVING max(aktywne) = 0
) x 
ON 
x.user_id = a.user_id and 
x.opis = a.opis
WHERE user_id = 6
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16774/6

Use [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on your setup to see what would work best for you.